# How do I adapt the following code to change Card colors dynamically in Cardview

Tags: java

Reading old questions I have and watching several tutorials I have written this code.

**RecyclerAdapter.java**

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {

String[] postText;
String[] groupName;

public RecyclerAdapter(String[] postText, String[] groupName){
    this.postText = postText;
    this.groupName = groupName;
}
@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)  {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view,parent,false);
    RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
    return recyclerViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.txPost.setText(postText[position]);
    holder.txGroupName.setText(groupName[position]);
    holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return postText.length;
}

public static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView txPost;
    TextView txGroupName;
    CardView cardView;
    public RecyclerViewHolder(View view)
    {
        super(view);
        txPost = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.post_text);
        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);

        txGroupName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.group_name);

    }
}
}
```

This works fine but now I need to change the colors randomly. I tried to pass an array string array of colors to the  `holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);` but it threw an error because it takes int. I am new to java and programming as a whole. What is the proper way of doing it?